# Change CLLocationCoordinate2DMake With array by indexPath

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, mkmapview, cllocationcoordinate2d

Im trying to code the `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` to change by an `array` so the lat and long will change depending on the `indxPath` ...
like i tried here:

```
var Longitude = ["32.101145","32.074961","",""]
var Latitude = ["34.775163","34.781679","","",""]


//What i tried :

    let LightHouseLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Longitude[indexPath.row],Latitude[indexPath.row])
            // Drop a pin
```

but of course its throwing errors on me . i will be grateful if anyone could help me, Thank you .

Comment: What error do you get? Pls elaborate on it. It seems you have your location up in place. The next step is to configure your `MKPointAnnotation` (pin) for your `LighthouseLocation` and add it to your map.

Comment: Why don't you have an array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, instead of two separate arrays for `latitude` and `longitude`?

Comment: Show your error, but I imagine it is because you are passing Strings not floats and in some cases those strings aren't even representations of floats, so you will need to deal with that

Comment: @TristanBeaton can you give me some example with snippet code please?

Comment: `var coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 32.101145, longitude: 34.775163),CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 32.074961, longitude: 34.781679)]`

Comment: @TristanBeaton can you make this work on the code i have ? also write as an answer so i can mark it as the answer.

Comment: I see that you are using `indexPath.row`. Where are you getting the `indexPath` from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var coordinates = Array<CLLocationCoordinate2D>()

        coordinates.append(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.101145, 32.074961))

        coordinates.append(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(34.775163, 34.781679))

        let pins = coordinates.map { (coordinate) -> MKPointAnnotation in

            let pin = MKPointAnnotation()

            pin.coordinate = coordinate

            return pin
        }

        self.map.addAnnotations(pins)
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't quite do it like that but you defiantly gave me the tools and the solution.Thank you.